# DBpedia Spotlight Statistical command line arguments

Tags: java, netbeans, dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I found this article:
[DBpedia Statistical Spotlight installation](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/issues/318#issuecomment-59652413)

I dont understand this line (broken up to separate the command line arguments):

```
4. run java 
       -Xmx10G 
       -Xms10G 
       -jar 
       dbpedia-spotlight-0.7.jar 
       ~/pathToModels/en/ 
       http://localhost:2222/rest
```

Can anyone explain these command line arguments to me?
I'm using NetBeans IDE and Glassfish server

Answer (score 0):

```
java                               --name of the program you are running (you will need a JRE)
       -Xmx10G                     --maximum memory to be allocated 10GB  
       -Xms10G                     --minimum memory to be allocated
       -jar                        --run the program from a jar file
       dbpedia-spotlight-0.7.jar   --the jar file containing the program
       ~/pathToModels/en/          --argument 1 to be passed to the program
       http://localhost:2222/rest  --argument 2, looks like the URL on which your server will run
```

Comment: thanx alot for your response..
I jus wonder where to type these commands... on cmd or what

Comment: In command prompt on windows or shell on linux/unix. If windows the ~/pathToModels/en/ argument may need to be changed appropriately (it looks like a unix path). You will need to check the products docs to see what that argument means